# How to set the array of objects from a class to a controller in tabbarviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, object, uitabbarcontroller, sharing

i have a class songsData in this i am parsing a json object and adding the song objects to an array and later setting this array of objects in a viewcontroller of atabbarviewcontroller. while accessing its showing o objects in tabbarcontroller

how to gt that array in the viewcontroller of an tabbarcontroller.

thanks

```
in songsData.m
-(void)loadData{
    OnAirViewController *oAVC = [[OnAirViewController alloc]init];//the view controller in Tabbarcontroller
    oAVC.songs = [self parsingTheJson:@"http:....."];
    NSLog(@" count..%d",[songs count]);//gives 153
}
```

in onAirViewController..
its giving

```
NSLog(@" count..%d",[songs count]);//gives 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the controller that is in your tab bar is the exact same instance of `OnAirViewController` that you are creating in `loadData`? Assuming that the tab bar controller is already initialized when `loadData` is called, you would not create a fresh instance of `OnAirViewController` but rather assign the array to the existing `OnAirViewController` instance.